# Create screenshot - Allure, JUnit5, Selenium

Tags: selenium, screenshot, junit5, allure

Is there any documentation about this? JUnit4 has @Rule and solution is straightforward. For JUnit5 I made a extension `public class TestWatcher implements AfterTestExecutionCallback` but I don't know what to put in @Override method.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve it. Method for screen capture is default one:

```
@Attachment(value = "{testName} - screenshot", type = "image/png")
private byte[] makeScreenshotOnFailure(String testName) {

    return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
}
```

and TestWatcher (extension):

```
@Override
public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {

    Object test = extensionContext.getRequiredTestInstance();
    Field a = test.getClass().getDeclaredField("driver");
    a.setAccessible(true);
    driver = (WebDriver) a.get(test);

    Method method = extensionContext.getRequiredTestMethod();
    if (extensionContext.getExecutionException().isPresent()) {
        makeScreenshotOnFailure(method.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find a sample [here](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/noraui/service/impl/ScreenServiceImpl.java). Is it a code from [NoraUi](https://noraui.github.io/) Open Source Framework (Java + Selenium).

```
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) Context.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
```